# scroll to particular element inside iframe

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, html, iframe, scroll

I want to scroll to a particular element inside iframe. My code looks like this.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            var $contents = $('#url_iframe').contents();
            $contents.scrollTo($contents.html().find('mark'));
        }, 3000); // ms = 3 sec
    });
```

But it doesnt seems to work. any ideas or help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

no need of `html()` function there...

try this

```
 $contents.scrollTo($contents.find('#mark'));
                    //-------^^-- no need html() here
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are making a cross browser reference. Major browsers won't allow you to do that.

Answer (score 0):

`iframe`s can be scrolled like any other scrollable element. But you need to be aware that it's a nested document (so offsets are relative to the top/left corner of the iframe + if you want the position of a div in the iframe, you must use `$("#iFrame").contents().find("#someDiv"))`